# Java Iterators and Streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to convert a loop that I have made into Java streams, though the code uses `iterators` and I am finding it hard to convert it into readable code.

```
private void printKeys() throws IOException {
    ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();

    // read a json file
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode root = objectMapper.readTree(classLoader.getResource("AllSets.json"));
    Set<String> names = new HashSet<>();

    // loop through each sub node and store the keys
    for (JsonNode node : root) {
        for (JsonNode cards : node.get("cards")) {
            Iterator<String> i = cards.fieldNames();
            while(i.hasNext()){
                String name = i.next();
                names.add(name);
            }
        }
    }

    // print each value
    for (String name : names) {
        System.out.println(name);
    }

   }
```

I have tried the following though I feel like its not going the right way.

```
List<JsonNode> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
root.iterator().forEachRemaining(nodes::add);

Set<JsonNode> cards = new HashSet<>();
nodes.stream().map(node -> node.get("cards")).forEach(cards::add);

Stream s = StreamSupport.stream(cards.spliterator(), false);
//.. unfinished and unhappy
```

You can find the Json file I used here: https://mtgjson.com/json/AllSets.json.zip
Be warned its quite large.

Comment: Could you attach `AllSets.json` to test code, please?

Comment: @AndriiAbramov I added a link to the file in the question.

Answer (score 3):

You can do most of the things in one swoop, but it's a shame this json [api](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html) does not support streams better.

```
List<JsonNode> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
root.iterator().forEachRemaining(nodes::add);

Set<String> names = nodes.stream()
    .flatMap(node -> StreamSupport.stream(
        node.get("cards").spliterator(), false))
    .flatMap(node -> StreamSupport.stream(
        ((Iterable<String>) () -> node.fieldNames()).spliterator(), false))
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Or with Patrick's helper method (from the comments):

```
Set<String> names = stream(root)
    .flatMap(node -> stream(node.get("cards")))
    .flatMap(node -> stream(() -> node.fieldNames()))
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

...

```
public static <T> Stream<T> stream(Iterable<T> itor) {
    return StreamSupport.stream(itor.spliterator(), false);
}
```

And printing:

```
names.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: This could look a lot better with a helper method `public static <T> Stream<T> stream(Iterable<T> itor) { return StreamSupport.stream(itor.spliterator(), false); }`

Answer (score 0):

If you provide 'json' file to us, it will be very useful.

At least now, I can make some suggestions to you:

```
Set<JsonNode> cards = new HashSet<>();
nodes.stream().map(node -> node.get("cards")).forEach(cards::add);
```

Replace with:

```
Set<JsonNode> cards = nodes.stream().map(node -> node.get("cards")).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

---

```
for (String name : names) {
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

Replace with:

```
names.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Added a link to the json file in the original question

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
Set<JsonNode> cards = new HashSet<>();
```

with

```
List<JsonNode> cards = new ArrayList<>();
```

Remove

```
Stream s = StreamSupport.stream(cards.spliterator(), false);
```

Then add below lines

```
cards.stream().forEach( card -> {
    Iterable<String> iterable = () -> card.fieldNames();
    Stream<String> targetStream = StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false);
    targetStream.forEach(names::add);
});
names.forEach(System.out::println);
```